# How to make a hierarchical structure based on multi level data

Tags: pandas, oracle

I have input like with two levels of node as below where Node 1 is a parent node and node 2 is a child. But some child in node 2 like B1, B2, H9 can also have a child and be a parent in node 1.

[image]

How to generate the hierarchical structure based on this data via Oracle SQL or Pandas dataframe?

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) with [`all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Node 1', target='Node 2',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                           )

roots = (v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]

out = (pd.DataFrame(path for root in roots for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaves))
        .add_prefix('Node_')
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  Node_0 Node_1 Node_2
0     A1     B1     K5
1     A1     B1     I2
2     A1     B2     J1
3     A1     B2     K5
4     A2     B1     K5
5     A2     B1     I2
6     A2     B3   None
7     A3     G7   None
8     A3     H9     L7
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: If the values in Node1 and Node2 have multiple revisions mentioned in two other columns, plus there will be additional columns in the input which should come in the final output as well. how to generate the structure considering the revisions. For the graph, the source should be Node1 + Node_Revision and Target should be Node2 + Node_Revision??

Comment: @Osceria you can use tuples as node identifiers. If this is unclear, maybe open a new question and let me know. (make sure to provide a [mre], not images).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78193430/generating-graph-like-structure-based-on-multiple-columns-using-python

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN PRIOR node1 ELSE node1 END AS node0,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN node1 ELSE node2 END AS node1,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 2 THEN node2 END AS node2
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
OR     (LEVEL = 1 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1)
START WITH node1 LIKE 'A%'
CONNECT BY PRIOR node2 = node1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(node1, node2) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'B3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'K5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'I2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'G7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'H9' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2', 'K5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'H9', 'L7' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NODE0 | NODE1 | NODE2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | I2 |
| A1 | B1 | K5 |
| A1 | B2 | J1 |
| A1 | B2 | K5 |
| A2 | B1 | I2 |
| A2 | B1 | K5 |
| A2 | B3 | *null* |
| A3 | G7 | *null* |
| A3 | H9 | L7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k6JYkVRs)

Comment: It throws "error : ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data" for large dataset

Comment: @Osceria Then you have a loop in your data. Either fix your data so it does not have loops or use `CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ....`.

Comment: Used CONNECT BY NOCYCLE to resolve the error