# Generating graph like structure based on multiple columns using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns: Node1, Node2, Node1_REV, and Node2_REV. In this structure, Node1 serves as a parent node, while Node2 functions as a child node. Both Node1_REV and Node2_REV capture different revisions of their respective nodes. ChildNode values may possess their own child values, indicated in columns ChildNode and ChildNode_Rev.

For instance, B1/1, B2/1, and B2/2 have their own child values in the ChildNode/ChildNode_Rev columns. Additionally, values such as B1/1 may appear in different ParentNodes like A1/1 and A2/1, while values like B2/1 may appear in A1/2, with different revisions like B2/2 potentially appearing in another ParentNode like A2/2.

This hierarchical chain continues until a path is established where a parentNode doesn't appear as a childNode to any other values.

To generate the desired output, it's necessary to traverse through all the values, identifying all possible levels and combinations until the top node is reached. When checking for possible links, the combination of Node+Rev should be considered unique, rather than just the Node value alone.

- **Sample Input Dataframe:**

| Node1 | Node1_Rev | Node2 | Node2_REV | REF | DES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A1 | 2 | B2 | 1 | 12 | SG |
| A2 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A2 | 2 | B2 | 2 | 12 | SG |
| B1 | 1 | K5 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| B1 | 1 | K1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| B2 | 2 | T1 | 1 | 12 | S1 |
| A3 | 2 | G7 | 2 | 12 | G2A3 |
| A3 | 3 | H9 | 1 | 23 | ... |
| B2 | 1 | J1 | 3 | 22 | SSD |

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Node1': ['A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B2','A3','A3','B2'],
                    'Node1_Rev': ['1','2','1','2','1','2','2','3','1'],
                    'Node2': ['B1','B2','B1','B2','K5','T1','G7','H9','J1'],
                    'Node2_Rev': ['1','1', '1','2','1','1','2','1','3'],
                    'REF' : ['11','12','11','12','11','12','12','23','22'],
                    'DES' : ['QR','SG','QW','SG','QR','S1','G2A3','...','SSD']
}
)
```

- **Sample Output Dataframe:**

| Node0 | Node0_Rev | Node1 | Node1_REV | Node2 | Node2_REV | REF | DES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A1 | 2 | A1 | 2 | B2 | 1 | 12 | SG |
| A2 | 1 | A2 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A2 | 2 | A2 | 2 | B2 | 2 | 12 | SG |
| A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 | K5 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A2 | 1 | B1 | 1 | K1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A2 | 2 | B2 | 2 | T1 | 1 | 12 | S1 |
| A3 | 2 | A3 | 2 | G7 | 2 | 12 | G2A3 |
| A3 | 3 | A3 | 3 | H9 | 1 | 23 | ... |
| A1 | 2 | B2 | 1 | J1 | 3 | 22 | SSD |

[image]

What are the efficient ways to generate the output for a bigger dataset?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway Opened this new question to enhance the [How to make a hierarchical structure based on multi level data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75315046/how-to-make-a-hierarchical-structure-based-on-multi-level-data/75315212?noredirect=1#comment137850403_75315212)

Comment: I don't see the difference between input and output DataFrame, apart from the fact that TopNode_Rev is a copy of ParentNode_REV

Comment: In the output dataframe, values of TopNode in the rows 5,6,7,10 will be different than the ParentNode because B1/1, B2/2, B2/1 appear in both ChildNode and ParentNode columns

Comment: So a node has both data and children, is that correct?

Comment: If we consider a row as node, yes.

Comment: The diagram is super helpful but alas, it does not represent either of your example data? For example, where do the node `k1/1` come from? Also, what value does node `b1/1` have? Is it `11,QR` or `11,QW` or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the typos. Corrected the data in the question

Comment: It remains unclear what is the role of REF/DES, I guess you might need to `merge` them in the output table. Please clarify and break down the logic if this is important.

Comment: REF and DES are just additional columns that need to be added to the output dataframe

Comment: But added **how**? Since they won't necessarily match the paths

Answer (score 0):

Following my previous answer, you can adapt the code to build the DataFrame from tuples instead of single values:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist((zip(zip(df['Node1'], df['Node1_Rev']),
                          zip(df['Node2'], df['Node2_Rev']))),
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = (v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]

out = (pd.DataFrame(path for root in roots for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaves))
        .add_prefix('Node_')
      )
```

Output:

```
    Node_0   Node_1   Node_2
0  (A1, 1)  (B1, 1)  (K5, 1)
1  (A1, 2)  (B2, 1)  (J1, 3)
2  (A2, 1)  (B1, 1)  (K5, 1)
3  (A2, 2)  (B2, 2)  (T1, 1)
4  (A3, 2)  (G7, 2)     None
5  (A3, 3)  (H9, 1)     None
```

Graph:

[image]

---

##### optimization and output as columns

To improve efficiency, we can only test pairs of root/leaf in the subgraphs of connected components. For that there are two approaches, generate the groups, roots, leaves and then filter them with set operations or generate the groups/roots/leaves on the fly. Which one is better might depends on the organization of the graph, the number of subgraphs, etc.

In any case, if there are large subgraphs (connected components) with multiple roots and leaves, one row per combination is geenrated, thus this can quickly explode. For instance, if you have a group with 10 roots and 10 leaves, 100 rows are generated.

First approach:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist((zip(zip(df['Node1'], df['Node1_Rev']),
                          zip(df['Node2'], df['Node2_Rev']))),
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)

roots = {v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0}
leaves = {v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0}

c = nx.weakly_connected_components(G)

out = (pd.concat(dict(enumerate(
                   pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['', '_rev'])
                    for g in c
                    for root in roots&g
                    for l in [leaves&g]
                    for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, l))
                     ), axis=1)
        .stack().T
      )
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'Node{x[0]}{x[1]}')
```

Second approach:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist((zip(zip(df['Node1'], df['Node1_Rev']),
                          zip(df['Node2'], df['Node2_Rev']))),
                    create_using=nx.DiGraph)

out = (pd.concat(dict(enumerate(
                   pd.DataFrame(path, columns=['', '_rev'])
                    for g in map(G.subgraph, nx.weakly_connected_components(G))
                    for root in (v for v, d in g.in_degree() if d == 0)
                    for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, {v for v, d in g.out_degree() if d == 0}))
                     ), axis=1)
        .stack().T
      )
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'Node{x[0]}{x[1]}')
```

Output:

```
  Node0 Node0_rev Node1 Node1_rev Node2 Node2_rev
0    A1         1    B1         1    K5         1
1    A1         2    B2         1    J1         3
2    A2         1    B1         1    K5         1
3    A2         2    B2         2    T1         1
4    A3         2    G7         2   NaN       NaN
5    A3         3    H9         1   NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Can we generate the columns for n number of levels in the output dataframe- Node0, Node0_Rev, Node1, Node1_Rev, ........NodeN, NodeN_Rev

Comment: it worked for a smaller dataset. However, it runs for long hours against a bigger dataset and the kernel dies. Is there a way to address this?

Comment: @Osceria I updated the code with an optimized version, it only forms the paths within connected components. Note however that since one path/row is formed per pair of root/leaf this might be impossible to generate all combinations if subgroups have many roots+leaves.

Comment: When you test on a bigger dataset, are you sure that there is no loop in the directed graph?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to collect the data into your directed network, though it does not produce the final table as this supports an arbitrarily deep graph.

```py
import io
import json

rows= """
| A1 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A1 | 2 | B2 | 1 | 12 | SG |
| A2 | 1 | B1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| A2 | 2 | B2 | 2 | 12 | SG |
| B1 | 1 | K5 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| B1 | 1 | K1 | 1 | 11 | QR |
| B2 | 2 | T1 | 1 | 12 | S1 |
| A3 | 2 | G7 | 2 | 12 | G2A3 |
| A3 | 3 | H9 | 1 | 23 | ... |
| B2 | 1 | J1 | 3 | 22 | SSD |
""".strip()

rows_collector = {}
with io.StringIO(rows) as file_in:
    for row in file_in:
        fields = [f.strip() for f in row.strip(" |").split("|")]
        parent_key = fields[0:2]
        parent_node, parent_rev = parent_key
        parent_key = "~".join(parent_key)

        child_key = fields[2:4]
        child_node, child_rev = child_key
        child_key = "~".join(child_key)

        child_data = fields[4:6]

        child = rows_collector.setdefault(child_key, {
            "node": child_node,
            "rev": child_rev,
            "children": [],
        })
        child["REF"] = child_data[0]
        child["DES"] = child_data[1]
        child["has_parent"] = True

        parent = rows_collector.setdefault(parent_key, {
            "node": parent_node,
            "rev": parent_rev,
            "REF" : None,
            "DES" : None,
            "children" : [],
            "has_parent": False
        })
        parent["children"].append(child)

for key, value in sorted(rows_collector.items()):
    if not value["has_parent"]:
        print(json.dumps(value, indent=4))
```

That will give you back:

```
{
    "node": "A1",
    "rev": "1",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "B1",
            "rev": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "node": "K5",
                    "rev": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "11",
                    "DES": "QR",
                    "has_parent": true
                },
                {
                    "node": "K1",
                    "rev": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "11",
                    "DES": "QR",
                    "has_parent": true
                }
            ],
            "REF": "11",
            "DES": "QR",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
{
    "node": "A1",
    "rev": "2",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "B2",
            "rev": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "node": "J1",
                    "rev": "3",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "22",
                    "DES": "SSD",
                    "has_parent": true
                }
            ],
            "REF": "12",
            "DES": "SG",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
{
    "node": "A2",
    "rev": "1",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "B1",
            "rev": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "node": "K5",
                    "rev": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "11",
                    "DES": "QR",
                    "has_parent": true
                },
                {
                    "node": "K1",
                    "rev": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "11",
                    "DES": "QR",
                    "has_parent": true
                }
            ],
            "REF": "11",
            "DES": "QR",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
{
    "node": "A2",
    "rev": "2",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "B2",
            "rev": "2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "node": "T1",
                    "rev": "1",
                    "children": [],
                    "REF": "12",
                    "DES": "S1",
                    "has_parent": true
                }
            ],
            "REF": "12",
            "DES": "SG",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
{
    "node": "A3",
    "rev": "2",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "G7",
            "rev": "2",
            "children": [],
            "REF": "12",
            "DES": "G2A3",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
{
    "node": "A3",
    "rev": "3",
    "REF": null,
    "DES": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "H9",
            "rev": "1",
            "children": [],
            "REF": "23",
            "DES": "...",
            "has_parent": true
        }
    ],
    "has_parent": false
}
```